# Given a number N, can N be expressed as the sum of two or more consecutive perfect squares?

Tags: java, algorithm, math

At a recent computer programming competition that I was at, there was a problem where you have to determine if a number N, for 1<=N<=1000, is a palindromic square. A palindromic square is number that can be read the same forwards and backwards and can be expressed as the sum of two or more consecutive perfect squares. For example, 595 is a palindrome and can be expressed as 6^2 + 7^2 + 8^2 + 9^2 + 10^2 + 11^2 + 12^2.

I understand how to determine if the number is a palindrome, but I'm having trouble trying to figure out if it can be expressed as the sum of two or more consecutive squares.

Here is the algorithm that I tried:

```html
public static boolean isSumOfSquares(int num) {
         int sum = 0;
         int lowerBound = 1;

         //largest square root that is less than num
         int upperBound = (int)Math.floor(Math.sqrt(num)); 
         
         while(lowerBound != upperBound) {
             for(int x=lowerBound; x<upperBound; x++) {
                 sum += x*x;
             }
             
             if(sum != num) {
                 lowerBound++;
             }
             else {
                 return true;
             }
             sum=0;
                                                
         }
         
         return false;
     }
```

My approach sets the upper boundary to the closest square root to the number and sets the lower bound to 1 and keeps evaluating the sum of squares from the lower bound to the upper bound. The issue is that only the lower bound changes while the upper bound stays the same.

Comment: is this the USACO problem?

Comment: 11 is palindrome but cannot be expressed as ^2 in a consecutive way . is that acceptable?

Comment: Please, Set sum To 0 Before The For Loop, And Check Condition sum < num Inside It.

Comment: 5 would be one: 1^2 + 2^2, correct? Making sure I understand.

Comment: One glaring error is you do not reset sum every time through the loop

Comment: My first thought is that a palindrome is not a mathematical concept. It is a visual one. In programming, it would be a string. So a general algorithm to determine if a number is a palindrome would be: 1) Convert it to a string, 2) Compare the string value against the reverse string value. (`string.reverse()` in Java I believe)

Comment: Never use `Math.pow(x,y)` for any integer `y`, all you do is buying floating point errors by saving time. Do repeated squaring or something like that for larger `y`, and plain `x*x` for something like this.

Comment: @jwatts his question is not about checking if a number is palindrome or not , he figured that out. he wants to get the second part the sequence of ^2

Comment: @Alundrathedreamwalker got it, I missed that part.

Comment: @jwatts NP , i like this kind of problems

Comment: @JoshuaByer Sorry, I was in a rush to rewrite the algorithm that I had for the competition and completely forgot to reset sum to 0 after every iteration.

Comment: @lacraig2 No, this is a University Interscholastic League (UIL) Computer Science problem.

Comment: @G.Bach Thank you for the advice. I didn't know that before.

Comment: This is project Euler problem 125, https://projecteuler.net/problem=125

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be an efficient algorithm for determining if it's a sum of squares of consecutive numbers.

1. Start with a lower bound and upper bound of 1.  The current sum of squares is `1`.

   ```
   public static boolean isSumOfSquares(int num) {
       int sum = 1;
       int lowerBound = 1;
       int upperBound = 1;
   ```
2. The maximum possible upper bound is the maximum number whose square is less than or equal to the number to test.

   ```
   int max = (int) Math.floor(Math.sqrt(num));
   ```
3. While loop.  If the sum of squares is too little, then add the next square, incrementing `upperBound`.  If the sum of squares is too high, then subtract the first square, incrementing `lowerBound`.  Exit if the number is found.  If it can't be expressed as the sum of squares of consecutive numbers, then eventually `upperBound` will exceed the `max`, and `false` is returned.

   ```
   while(sum != num)
   {
        if (sum < num)
        {
            upperBound++;
            sum += upperBound * upperBound;
        }
        else if (sum > num)
        {
            sum -= lowerBound * lowerBound;
            lowerBound++;
        }
        if (upperBound > max)
            return false;
   }

   return true;
   ```

Tests for `5`, `11`, `13`, `54`, `181`, and `595`.  Yes, some of them aren't palindromes, but I'm just testing the sum of squares of consecutive numbers part.

```
1: true
2: false
3: false
4: true
5: true
11: false
13: true
54: true
180: false
181: true
595: true
596: false
```

Comment: @Downvoter Please explain how you think this can be improved.

Comment: Your solution is wonderfully concise, but I wonder if upperBound should be set to 2 because it is asking for consecutive squares and you are initially setting lowerBound and upperBound as the same square. In the case of 1, the output should be false because 1 can't be expressed as a sum of two or more consecutive squares (1^2 + 1^2 doesn't work).

Comment: With `upperBound` and `lowerBound` set to `1`, that represents only one square, 1^2.  Does 0 count?  If so, 0^2 + 1^2 counts.  If it must be 2 or more consecutive squares, then you just make sure that `upperBound` is greater than `lowerBound` before returning `true`.

Comment: The problem didn't state whether 0 is considered a perfect square or not. That's something that needs clarification. But yes, checking to make sure upperBound is greater than lowerBound is necessary because it does have to be two or more consecutive squares.

Comment: This isn't correct. It doesn't find, for example, 11^2 + 12^2 = 265 because 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + ... + 10^2 > 265, so 11 and 12 are never considered.

Comment: @RobertDodier Your claim is incorrect.  I just included `265` in my test cases, and it returned `true`.  Please consider what my code does if the sum is greater than `265` -- it will advance `lowerBound`, subtracting from the sum.  It will eventually reach 11^2 + 12^2 = 265.

Answer (score 1):

Just for play, I created a Javascript function that gets all of the palindromic squares between a min and max value: http://jsfiddle.net/n5uby1wd/2/

HTML

```
<button text="click me" onclick="findPalindromicSquares()">Click Me</button>
<div id="test"></div>
```

JS

```
function isPalindrome(val) {
    return ((val+"") == (val+"").split("").reverse().join(""));
}

function findPalindromicSquares() {
    var max = 1000;
    var min = 1;
    var list = [];
    var done = false, 
        first = true, 
        sum = 0,
        maxsqrt = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(max)),
        sumlist = [];

    for(var i = min; i <= max; i++) {
        if (isPalindrome(i)) {
            done = false;

            //Start walking up the number list
            for (var j = 1; j <= maxsqrt; j++) {
                first = true;
                sum = 0;
                sumlist = [];

                for(var k = j; k <= maxsqrt; k++) {
                    sumlist.push(k);
                    sum = sum + (k * k);

                    if (!first && sum == i) {
                        list.push({"Value":i,"Sums":sumlist});
                        done = true;
                    }
                    else if (!first && sum > i) {
                        break;
                    }

                    first = false;
                    if (done) break;
                }

                if (done) break;
            }
        }
    }

    //write the list
    var html = "";
    for(var l = 0; l < list.length; l++) {
        html += JSON.stringify(list[l]) + "<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = html;
}
```

Where min=1 and max=1000, returns:

```
{"Value":5,"Sums":[1,2]}
{"Value":55,"Sums":[1,2,3,4,5]}
{"Value":77,"Sums":[4,5,6]}
{"Value":181,"Sums":[9,10]}
{"Value":313,"Sums":[12,13]}
{"Value":434,"Sums":[11,12,13]}
{"Value":505,"Sums":[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]}
{"Value":545,"Sums":[16,17]}
{"Value":595,"Sums":[6,7,8,9,10,11,12]}
{"Value":636,"Sums":[4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]}
{"Value":818,"Sums":[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]}
```

An updated version which allows testing individual values: http://jsfiddle.net/n5uby1wd/3/
It only took a few seconds to find them all between 1 and 1,000,000.

Comment: This question is tagged java, not javascript.

Comment: @rgettman I know. But the question was more about understanding how to approach the problem than having the exact code. Besides, it is a fun problem to solve, and JSfiddle gives quick and easy access to test and see results.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for S(n, k) = n^2 + (n + 1)^2 + (n + 2)^2 + ... (n + (k - 1))^2 which adds up to a specified sum m, i.e., S(n, k) = m. (I'm assuming you'll test for palindromes separately.) S(n, k) - m is a quadratic in n. You can easily work out an explicit expression for S(n, k) - m, so solve it using the quadratic formula. If S(n, k) - m has a positive integer root, keep that root; it gives a solution to your problem.

I'm assuming you can easily test whether a quadratic has a positive integer root. The hard part is probably determining whether the discriminant has an integer square root; I'm guessing you can figure that out.

You'll have to look for k = 2, 3, 4, .... You can stop when 1 + 4 + 9 + ... + k^2 > m. You can probably work out an explicit expression for that.

Comment: Correction: you should square n in the first line. In any case, I believe S(n,k) is cubic in both n and k. You get a cubic Diophantine equation in two variables ... probably not easy to solve.

Comment: @EdwardDoolittle S(n, k) is quadratic in n and cubic in k. But k is a given, not a variable you have to solve for. Finding the maximum k does require solving a cubic but a simple bisection or even a linear search will do. So I'm not seeing that there is a problem.

Comment: You're right, quadratic in n. When I solve the equation for n, I get the following discriminant: `-3(k+1)(k^3+3k^2+2k-12m)`. That needs to be a perfect square. Let's take m = 595 as an example. How do we ensure that is a perfect square without testing a whole bunch of values of k (which would probably be as much work as just summing the series)?

Comment: Go to http://www.wolframalpha.com and input this expression 1/6*(n+k)*(n+k+1)*(2*(n‌​+k)+1) - 1/6*(n-1)*(n)*(2*(n-1)+1) - m

Comment: Well, the maximum value of k is on the order of the cube root of 3m. For m = 595, it's exactly 12. It's not a big deal to test all k = 2, 3, 4, ... 12. For m = 10^6, the maximum k is 144; again, not a big deal to test all values. I realize that for large enough m, the burden of finding any k to satisfy S(n, k) = m will dominate the rest of the problem, and then we'll have to devise a better way to find perfect square discriminants. Re: Wolfram Alpha -- I don't understand what I would want to do with those expressions. Anyway I'm more comfortable with [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net).

Comment: I took another look at this, and I like your solution. The expression in my previous comment is exactly S(n,k)-m; Wolfram Alpha solves it for n. I posted it to fill in details for others.

Answer (score 0):

One method (probably not efficient) I can think of off the top of my head is, 
Suppose N is 90.
**X=9** (integer value of sqrt of 90)
 1. Create an array of all the integer powers less than x [1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81]
 
2. Generate all possible combinations of the items in the array using **recursion**. [1,4],[1,9],[1,16],....[4,1],[4,9],....[1,4,9]....
3. For each combination (as you generate)- check if the sum of add up to N

**To save memory space, upon generating each instance, you can verify if it sums up to N. If not, discard it and move on to the next.

One of the instances will be [9,81] where 9+81=[90]

Answer (score 0):

1. since there are only few integer powers, you can create an array of powers.
2. Then you can have 1st and last included index. Initially they are both 1.
3. while sum is lower than your number, increase last included index.  Update sum
4. while sum is higher, increase 1st included index.  Update sum

Or without any array, as in rgettman's answer

Comment: I like this answer, since it just outlines the method and omits the code, which is much harder to understand. That said, it is incorrect in the same way as rgettman's answer. It doesn't find, for example, 11^2 + 12^2 = 265 because 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + ... + 10^2 > 265, so 11 and 12 are never considered.

Comment: when the sum becomes >265, you do point 4. (subtract from 265 first squares in the sequence)

Comment: Yeah, I didn't understand from the description that you go back to step 3 after step 4.

Answer (score 0):

Start with an array of The first perfect squares, Let's say your numbers are 13 and 17 , then your array will contain: 1, 4, 9, and 16

Do this kind of checking:

---

13 minus 1 (0^2) is 12. 1 is a perfect square, 12 is not.

13 minus 2(1^2) is 11. 2 is a perfect square, 11 is not.

13 minus 4(2^2) is 9. 4 is a perfect square, 9 is a perfect square, so **13 is the sum of two perfect**

17 minus 1 is 16. 1 and 16 **are perfect squares**. Eliminate choice.

Keep going until you find one that is not the sum of two perfect squares or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can determine whether a number is a sum of consecutive squares quickly in the following manner, which vastly reduces the amount of arithmetic that needs to be done. First, precompute all the sums of squares and place them in an array:

```
0, 0+1=1, 1+4=5, 5+9=14, 14+16=30, 30+25=55, 55+36=91, ...
```

Now, if a number is the sum of two or more consecutive squares, we can complete it by adding a number from the above sequence to obtain another number in the above sequence. For example, 77=16+25+36, and we can complete it by adding the listed number 14=0+1+4+9 to obtain the listed number 91=14+77=(0+1+4+9)+(16+25+36). The converse holds as well, provided the two listed numbers are at least two positions apart on the list.

How long does our list have to be? We can stop when we add the first square of `n` which satisfies `(n-1)^2+n^2 > max` where `max` in this case is 1000. Simplifying, we can stop when `2(n-1)^2 > max` or `n > sqrt(max/2) + 1`. So for `max=1000`, we can stop when `n=24`.

To quickly test membership in the set, we should hash the numbers in the list as well as storing them in the list; the value of the hash should be the location of the number in the list so that we can quickly locate its position to determine whether it is at least two positions away from the starting point.

Here's my suggestion in Java:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class SumOfConsecutiveSquares {

  // UPPER_BOUND is the largest N we are testing;
  static final int UPPER_BOUND = 1000;
  // UPPER_BOUND/2, sqrt, then round up, then add 1 give MAX_INDEX
  static final int MAX_INDEX = (int)(Math.sqrt(UPPER_BOUND/2.0)) + 1 + 1;

  static int[] sumsOfSquares = new int[MAX_INDEX+1];
  static HashMap<Integer,Integer> sumsOfSquaresHash
    = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();

  // pre-compute our list
  static {
    sumsOfSquares[0] = 0;
    sumsOfSquaresHash.put(0,0);
    for (int i = 1; i <= MAX_INDEX; ++i) {
      sumsOfSquares[i] = sumsOfSquares[i-1] + i*i;
      sumsOfSquaresHash.put(sumsOfSquares[i],i);
    }
  }

  public static boolean isSumOfConsecutiveSquares(int N) {
    for (int i=0; i <= MAX_INDEX; ++i) {
      int candidate = sumsOfSquares[i] + N;
      if (sumsOfSquaresHash.containsKey(candidate)
          && sumsOfSquaresHash.get(candidate) - i >= 2) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i=0; i < 1000; ++i) {
      if (isSumOfConsecutiveSquares(i)) {
        System.out.println(i);
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Each run of the function performs at most 25 additions and 25 hash table lookups. No multiplications.

To use it efficiently to solve the problem, construct 1, 2, and 3-digit palindromes (1-digit are easy: 1, 2, ..., 9; 2-digit by multiplying by 11: 11, 22, 33, ..., 99; 3-digit by the formula i*101 + j*10. Then check the palindromes with the function above and print out if it returns true.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static boolean isSumOfSquares(int num) {
         int sum = 0;
         int lowerBound = 1;

         //largest square root that is less than num
         int upperBound = (int)Math.floor(Math.sqrt(num)); 

         while(lowerBound != upperBound) {
             sum = 0
             for(int x=lowerBound; x<upperBound; x++) {
                 sum += x * x;
             }

             if(sum != num) {
                 lowerBound++;
             }
             else {
                 return true;
             }
         }

         return false;
     }
```

Comment: This Not Works As Expected For 595, Check sum < num In For Loop Condition.

Comment: You are wrong, walk through the code and question again

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps I am missing the point, but considering N, for 1<=N<=1000 the most efficient way would be to solve the problem some way (perhaps brute force) and store the solutions in a switch.

```
switch(n){
    case 5:
    case 13:
    ...
        return true;
    default:
        return false;
}
```

Comment: This is a non answer.

Comment: Right. And then somebody sets the upper bound to 2^64 and it takes you a lifetime to pre-compute the table, and a big disk drive on which to store it. And the guy who actually solved the problem just changes a few parameters in his code and is up and running in a few minutes.

Comment: @JimMischel I don't understand why the competition specified the range of n so narrowly, but they did.  Are you anticipating that the judges will change the rules mid-competition to benefit some competitors?

Comment: No, I doubt they'd do that. Your suggestion to create the lookup table so that you can return results quickly is not a useful answer because in order to create the lookup table you have to solve the OP's problem. So your answer amounts to telling the user to use the solution to his problem to solve his problem.

Comment: @JimMischel it looks like an easy problem to me if you take advantage of the limited range of n:  `for(int i = 0, i<1000;i++){System.out.println("case "+(i*i+(i+1)*(i+1)+":");}` will give you a lookup table that is larger than necessary (which is ok).

Answer (score -1):

```
public static boolean validNumber(int num) {
    if (!isPalindrome(num))
        return false;
    int i = 1, j = 2, sum = 1*1 + 2*2;
    while (i < j)
        if (sum >  num) {
            sum = sum - i*i; i = i + 1;
        } else if (sum <  num) {
            j = j + 1; sum = sum + j*j;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    return false;
}
```

However There Are Only Eleven "Good Numbers" { 5, 55, 77, 181, 313, 434, 505, 545, 595, 636, 818 }. And This Grows Very Slow, For N = 10^6, There Are Only 59.